# 60s or earlier sci-fi novel, involved suspected kidnapping and a main character named Jantz or Janz

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi novel I read as a kid (maybe mid-1960s, but the book might have been older than that) which, as I very vaguely recall, involved suspected kidnapping and a main character named Jantz or Janz. I recall it was set in a city (seemed like characters dwelled in apartments).

I don't recall any further detail (I want to find it to reread it) other than it was science fiction in that Jantz was suspected of being an alien or of working in concert with aliens. They needed (or so the plot implied) children for some nefarious purpose.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already (it seems like a pretty unique name), but it's also a bit terse - many stories take place in cities! :) May I encourage you to read [this helpful guide on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in?